# Add `color` attribute

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Colours add another dimension to text. We use them to educate children. Some use them in different note taking frameworks. Colours are awesome.

### [image: colourful mindmap]

Imagine how easier it would be to explain how this regex:

```
^.*?[a-zA-Z]*M\d+$
```

Matches this string:

```
awesome_ColoursM888888
```

If you could start like this:

[image: regex matching with colours example]

PS: Don't argue about the validity of the question or alternatives in this specific example. It's just an example.

---

**Update:** For all the people instantly assuming newbies and spammers will post unreadable rainbow mess, here are two possible solutions:

- Make it a privilege. You simply can't use colours if you don't have at least *x* reputation.
- Don't add UI for it. How many people actually know you can use `kbd` tag to make something appear as a button (<kbd>Shift</kbd>)? I would guess not that many, even though we actively encourage its use when appropriate. Out of those who know - probably almost none are complete newcomers.

Comment: Please no! This would make the look of posts incredibly distractive.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, there can be guidelines on when to use colours or people could just use common sense. I don't think you will suddenly see every second post be a Picasso masterpiece.

Comment: We have tons of formatting guidelines, and people consistently fail to follow them. Same with common sense. Using backticks for anything that isn't code, for example.

Comment: @Yannis, ok, then we should remove formatting as well, right? I mean, there are people that don't know how to use it, the benefit doesn't outway the cost?

Comment: I see no benefit in this. This isn't a necessary evil, this is just evil.

Comment: @Yannis, did you see the example? Are you seriously suggesting that colours don't have explanatory power in general?

Comment: The examples work against your proposal. Sure, colours do have explanatory power, the vibrant mess you presented in your examples does not. At least not for me.

Comment: That said, my opinion is just that and you shouldn't care about it. However, without giving us a sensible way of controlling even the most basic abuses of your feature (hey, look, each word/letter in my question is a different colour!), I don't see this being implemented.

Comment: @Yannis I never said question titles should have colours. Hell, they don't support basic formatting, look at this question's title. So your counter example is a fail. Could you add actual examples of how colours can be abused? We don't have it so we don't need it is not an argument.

Comment: When did I say anything about titles?

Comment: @Yannis So how is it abuse? If anything people will be less likely to answer your question if every letter is in different colour. It's like saying that people will start posting gibberish if we don't have forced spell checking.

Comment: Beyond the fact that this will lit up like a Christmas tree I also suspect an implementation issue as [CommonMark](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.25/) doesn't seem to support color and IIRC Stack Overflow is or will be moving towards that implementation. If anything, this FR would also need to fit in that spec.

Comment: In the rare cases that colours *would* help, such as your Regex example, you can just use a picture instead.

Comment: I vote no on this. I get your example, and agree that colors are helpful in that situation, but that's a very narrow subset of questions on SO. Can you think of how colors might be helpful in a broader sense? For a change like this, the benefits should far outweigh the potential for abuse.

Comment: I'm a super artsy, visually oriented person and not once in my six years have I missed this feature. The fewer formatting options there are, the better is the overall readability of the site's content.

Comment: Notice that the texts in your example picture are all black.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, everyone can find different uses, the possibilities are only limited by your imagination. In the same sense, what is the broader use of italics? I still don't understand how this can be abused. My understanding of abuse is taking advantage of something, not just using something to troll even though there is no point in doing so.

Comment: I see the merit for this in the context of your regex example, but it seems like this could lead to inconsistent highlighting and ugly, illegible posts - not to mention new users using it in an obnoxious way to highlight their post. It's easy to achieve a similar, more readable effect by breaking the regex up into a list of its parts and associating each individual part.

Answer (score 3):

> I still don't understand how this can be abused.

- White text to cram keywords, spam, and offensive text into posts.
- Defacing posts in a similar manner
- Making posts difficult to read by choosing colors with poor contrast
- Making it harder to see links because the color of the surrounding text and the link text now match
- Use of *just* color to convey information, harming post quality for blind/color-blind users

> In the same sense, what is the broader use of italics?

It's for emphasis, like in the last bullet point above. Italics and bold are pretty basic font styles and there's really no alternate way to convey emphasis other than all caps, which is generally read as shouting but can also be confused for the user writing an acronym.

Comment: My understanding of the word abuse is to use a feature in a way it was not intended **to gain an unfair advantage**. None of your examples do that. If you are worried people will use it to wreak havoc, they already have ways of doing that and we moderate them. If you are worried about people not knowing how to use the feature - there are a lot of people that don't know how to use the existing ones - we guide them and edit their posts.

Comment: As for blind/colour-blind people - this is even more a case in favour of adding it as an attribute of the text as opposed to being forced to create an image.

Comment: @ndn - There's not enough benefit to adding the feature to outweigh the negatives. The fact that they don't fall under that specific definition of abuse is irrelevant; they'd still be harmful to the site. There's no reason to waste resources adding something that will increase the moderation burden if it won't be useful.

Comment: If I didn't think it would be useful I wouldn't have brought it up in the first place. People keep repeating *"There's not enough benefit to adding the feature to outweigh the negatives."* yet noone has provided any data to support it. How did you measure the costs and benefits to come to this conclusion?

Comment: Also updated the question with solutions for the supposed danger of abuse.

Comment: @ndn Where is your data to support your assertion this will be beneficial to the site?  If your FR hinges on the regex case, that's a matter of syntax highlighting, meaning this FR is on the wrong website.  I forget which library or script does the pretty-ifying, but if you want highlighting for regex, I'd suggest making an FR for that specifically.  Otherwise, sure, people haven't provided evidence of danger, but you haven't provided any evidence to the contrary either.  Your own graph has all black text.

Comment: @Daedalus, it doesn't *"hinge"* on regexes. It says it's just an example right there in the question. The reason it makes sense that it would be beneficial is that it adds another dimension to text and we already use it in traditional education. The reason people will start posting colourful garbage is because? They simply can? They want to troll? As I said, even if we assume every single newbie and spammer comes to rainbowify SO once the feature is released, the *"danger"* can easily be mitigated in one of the ways proposed in the update of the question.

Comment: *If I didn't think it would be useful I wouldn't have brought it up in the first place.* @ndn - I wasn't saying that *you* don't think it's useful, I'm saying that you haven't proven that to anyone else. *noone has provided any data to support it* You're the one that wants to change the site. Where's your data that there is a significant benefit to this?

Comment: @BSMP, where was the data that SO will be useful at all before SO was created? Where was the data that italic and bold will be useful before they were added? As I said, we have reasons to believe that colours have explanatory power. I haven't seen someone stating the contrary so far. How useful will they be in the context of SO, I can not quantify until it has actually been implemented. Yet there are people like you that suggest that they know exactly how helpful and harmful it will be. When I already provided solutions for the *"harmful"* side of things.

Comment: @ndn - The solutions to mitigate the harm only matter if the benefit is worth it. For example, they recently blacklisted a bunch of link shorteners because the benefit didn't outweigh the hassle of having them. It looks like we simply aren't going to agree on this point: you want this implemented with little evidence it will be worth the effort, we think you ought to show how it will be broadly useful first.

Comment: @BSMP, assume we lived in a world where SO didn't have bold and italic. I'm very interested in what evidence you are going to provide that the benefit would outway the cost. Your initial argument revolved around imaginary strawmen rainbow spammers. And I provided a solution, even though I didn't think it will be a problem in the first place.

Comment: If people were making the argument that it's not requested enough feature to justify development cost, I would see that as a valid point. But only one person has pointed out possible difficulties with implementation and most of the arguments start with the assumption that the average SO user is a 10 yo troll.

Answer (score 2):

If you want colors, you can use a code snippet:

```css
.re-1 { color: red; }
.re-2 { color: orange; }
.re-3 { color: green; }
.re-4 { color: blue; }
```

```html
<p>^<span class="re-1">.*?</span><span class="re-2">[a-zA-Z]*</span><span class="re-3">M</span><span class="re-4">\d+</span>$</p>
<p><span class="re-1">awesome_</span><span class="re-2">Colours</span><span class="re-3">M</span><span class="re-4">888888</span></p>
```

To make it look prettier, you can only include the regular expression, the text, and some JS script. That script would tokenize the regular expression, match the given string, and display the result with CSS colors.

Comment: As I said, this was only an example. What if you wanted to use colours somewhere in the text of your explanation rather than highlight code in a different way? Would you force people to run a snippet so they read your post? If so, why do we have bold and italic at all, people could just use snippets if they wanted any formatting? Snippets are meant to demonstrate your examples/solution, not be part of the actual explanation.

Comment: @ndn Technically, Markdown doesn't have bold and italic which, like colors, wouldn't be semantic. It has text with strong importance, or with stress emphasis.